# mysql: strange error 1111 invalid use of group by

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-error-1111

Following is a query i am trying to run.

```
select location_data.trip_code,sum(max(device_time)-min(device_time)) from location_data,trip_management 
where location_data.source_id=3 and location_data.trip_code=trip_management.trip_code
group by location_data.trip_code
```

there are various trips  identified by trip_code in both trip_managemnet and location_data tables.these trips are taken by a single uniquely identified user (source_id=)3. what i am trying to do here is to sum all the time differences for each trip and then convert it into hh:mm:ss using the sec_to_time function to display the total time it took user 3 to take all of his trips.

the problem with above query is that it generates error 1111 as soon as i apply sum() over the difference of max and min device_time of each trip. i cant afford a subquery because this in itself is a subquery in a larger query.

I hope i explained the problem well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is that you are attempting to apply an aggregate `SUM()` over the aggregates `MAX(),MIN()`, but in fact the two levels operate on different groups. The inner one groups over `location_data.trip_code`, and the outer one groups over the result of that. You'll need to wrap it in a subquery:

```
SELECT
  trip_code,
  /* Outer query sums the inner aggregates */
  SUM(max_time - min_time) AS time_sum
FROM (
  SELECT 
    location_data.trip_code,
    /* Inner aggregates return the max & min times only */
    max(device_time) AS max_time,
    min(device_time) AS min_time
  FROM
     location_data,
     INNER JOIN trip_management ON location_data.trip_code = trip_management.trip_code
  WHERE
     location_data.source_id=3
  GROUP BY location_data.trip_code
) first_group
GROUP BY trip_code
```

I've also replaced you implicit join with an explicit `INNER JOIN`, which is the preferred syntax nowadays.

Comment: thanks alot :) but i was hoping to avoid a subquery to achieve the results. as i mentioned, this query initself is a subquery in a larger query. having nested subqueries will result in decreased performance, wont it? is there a way subquery could be avoided keeping the schema as it is?

Comment: @user1451836 A FROM subquery can't really be avoided in this situation because the `GROUP BY` clauses need to be applied in different contexts.  The performance here won't be nearly as poor as if you did them as subselects inside the `SUM()`. That could be orders of magnitude slower.  Your other option would be to cache the subquery as a materialized view, if it doesn't change often.

Comment: views wont work because incoming data is real-time, and to create views it will add a bit more complexity to the system. so, i assume this is the answer for my question. thanks Michael :)